# Should I exclude files when restoring /home folder from newer version?

Tags: 11.10, 10.04, restore

I'm reverting to 10.04 from 11.10 (Unity).  I have my entire /home folder backed up and plan to restore it to the new (10.04) system.  Are there any configuration files I should exclude because they will cause problems if I copy my current /home (11.10) to the /home in the older version (10.04)?

I'm simply trying to avoid a problem with settings or configurations that are not backward compatible.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this both ways but at the moment I would recommend restoring all files. Should there be a problem it is easy enough to remove that one or two troublesome configuration files from your home folder. After restoration, make sure that the permissions are right for each item as well!

Comment: Which files would you look to remove if you had problems?

Comment: Brian, I would remove some of the "." folders if I was having problems. For example, if any application like Firefox was acting up I would remove the .mozilla folder from my home. Others might take some searching to find the actual folder that contains the configuration data.